# Deep Learning how to split 5 dimensions timeseries and pass some dimensions through embedding layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have an input that is a time series of 5 dimensions:

`a = [[8,3],[2] , [4,5],[1], [9,1],[2]...]` `#total 100 timestamps. For each element, dims 0,1 are numerical data and dim 2 is a numerical encoding of a category. This is per sample, 3200 samples`

The category has 3 possible values (0,1,2)

I want to build a NN such that the last dimension (the category) will go through an embedding layer with output size 8, and then will be concatenated back to the first two dims (the numerical data).

So, this will be something like:

```
input1 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(2,)) #the numerical features
input2 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,)) #the encoding of the categories. this part will be embedded to 5 dims
x2 = Embedding(input_dim=1, output_dim = 8)(input2) #apply it to every timestamp and take only dim 3, so [2],[1], [2] 
x = concatenate([input1,x2]) #will get 10 dims at each timepoint, still 100 timepoints
x = LSTM(units=24)(x) #the input has 10 dims/features at each timepoint, total 100 timepoints per sample
x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(inputs=[input1, input2] , outputs=[x]) #input1 is 1D vec of the width 2 , input2 is 1D vec with the width 1 and it is going through the embedding
model.compile(
        loss='binary_crossentropy',
        optimizer='adam',
        metrics=['acc']
    )
```

How can I do it? (preferably in keras)?
My problem is how to apply the embedding to every time point?
Meaning, if I have 1000 timepoints with 3 dims each, I need to convert it to 1000 timepoints with 8 dims each (The emebedding layer should transform input2 from (1000X1) to (1000X8)

Comment: @AloneTogether yes (also I added another layer to the post as I want them to enter together to LSTM after the embedding)

Comment: @AloneTogether I have 3200 samples, each is ndarray of 100X5

Comment: @AloneTogether perhaps my explanation is poor, but I mean that the last 3 features will go together to the embedding and will transform to 8 features that are the embedding of these 3. So, for example, if the emebdding layer is e, so e([8,6,3] can be [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

Comment: Sorry, but as the tensorflow documentation clearly states, an embedding is not the correct layer to transform shape `(1000, 3)` to `(1000, 8)`. Please have a look at @Andrew Wei's answer. But be aware that no sort of encoding happens there!

But you did the encoding before isn't that correct?

Comment: @pythonic833 So I am not sure what is the solution - I cant put Dense layer as it will be different set of parameters per timestamp so it doesn't make sense. What can I do?

Comment: are the last 3 layers the result of one hot encoding?

Comment: I mean is the input2 the result of one hot encoding? It looks like that `[0, 1, 0],  [1, 0, 0]`. I mean then you would try to embed an encoding which doesn't really make sense. You would need to apply the embedding on the categories itself, e.g. 0 for `[1, 0, 0]`, 1 for `[0, 1, 0]` and 2 for `[0, 0, 1]`. Then use the embedding on the vector containing values of 0, 1 and 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of issues you are having here.
First let me give you a working example and explain along the way how to solve your issues.

##### Imports and Data Generation

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

num_timesteps = 100
max_features_values = [100, 100, 3]
num_observations = 2

input_list = [[[np.random.randint(0, v) for _ in range(num_timesteps)]
   for v in max_features_values]
    for _ in range(num_observations)]

input_arr = np.array(input_list)  # shape (2, 3, 100)
```

In order to use an embedding we need to the voc_size as input_dimension, as stated in the [LSTM documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding).

##### Embedding and Concatenation

```
voc_size = len(np.unique(input_arr[:, 2, :])) + 1  # 4
```

Now we need to create the inputs. Inputs should be of size `[None, 2, num_timesteps]` and `[None, 1, num_timesteps]` where the first dimension is the flexible and will be filled with the number of observations we are passing in. Let's use the embedding right after that using the previously calculated `voc_size`.

```py
inp1 = layers.Input(shape=(2, num_timesteps))  # TensorShape([None, 2, 100])
inp2 = layers.Input(shape=(1, num_timesteps))  # TensorShape([None, 1, 100])
x2 = layers.Embedding(input_dim=voc_size, output_dim=8)(inp2)  # TensorShape([None, 1, 100, 8])
x2_reshaped = tf.transpose(tf.squeeze(x2, axis=1), [0, 2, 1])  # TensorShape([None, 8, 100])
```

This cannot be easily concatenated since all dimensions must match except for the one along the concatenation axis. But the shapes are not matching unfortunately. Therefore we reshape `x2`. We do so by removing the first dimension and then transposing.

Now we can concatenate without any issue and everything works in a straight forward fashion:

```py
x = layers.concatenate([inp1, x2_reshaped], axis=1)
x = layers.LSTM(32)(x)
x = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(inputs=[inp1, inp2], outputs=[x])
```

##### Check on Dummy Example

```py
inp1_np = input_arr[:, :2, :]
inp2_np = input_arr[:, 2:, :]
model.predict([inp1_np, inp2_np])

# Output
# array([[0.544262 ],
#       [0.6157502]], dtype=float32)
```

#This outputs values between 0 and 1 just as expected.

Comment: I think your method produces a tensors of shape `(None, 100, 26)` rather than the desired `(None, 100, 10)`

Comment: @pythonic833 Thanks, Is there a way for me to see the output of layers.concatenate(tensorlist, axis=2)? It should be [100, 8] (100 timestamps, 8 dimes). Correspondly, the output of layers.Embedding(input_dim=voc_size, output_dim=8)(inp2) should be [100,5]

Comment: You can print it out. You might want to try running the example in colab and it'll print something like `KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 100, 26), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='concatenate_4/concat:0', description="created by layer 'concatenate_4'")`

Comment: @okuoub: I think you actually don't want an embedding but a layer which transforms your `(None, 100, 3)` shape to `(None, 100, 8)`. Because an embedding will create `None, 3, 100, 8)` which then makes it not possible to concat with the other input

Comment: @pythonic833 Yes, I want a layer which transforms your (None, 100, 3) shape to (None, 100, 8). I thought that Embedding is the way to do so. Is there better way?
Also, why embedding create [3,100,8] and not [100,8]?

Comment: @okuoub: Because that's how embeddings work (think of them as advanced and trainable dummy encoders). Why do you definitely need this intermediate shape?
EDIT: I mean intermediate shapes usually don't matter as long as the network works fine. Is there a more concrete idea that you are following from which one can find out what kind of layer you actually want to boost the dimensionality?

Comment: @pythonic833 I don't understand - the output of embedding isn't 1D? (for example word2vec..)
I need it because I want to enrich the dimensionality of the categorical features - I have one-hot encoding but the categories are not really all independent (category 1,0,0 is more similar to 0,1,0 then to 0,0,1) so I want the model to try to learn it

Comment: @okuoub: Comments aren't really the place to explain that, I refer you to this [tf documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/guide/word_embeddings), where you clearly see that it boosts the dimensionality (e.g. from `[1,2] to [[0.3, -1], [1.1, 3.4]]`). It sounds like you really should use embeddings, so could you please show in your question where you are doing the one hot encoding? So basically where your input vectors are coming from?

Comment: @pythonic833 Please see my edit, I hope it clear now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240067/discussion-between-pythonic833-and-okuoub).

Answer (score 4):

In case you are not looking for `Embedding`s the way it's usually used in Keras (positive integers mapping to dense vectors). You might be looking for some sort of unprojection or basis expansion, in which 3 dimensions get mapped (embedded) to 8 and concatenating the result. This can be done using the kernel trick or other methods, but also happens implicitly in neural networks with non-linear applications.

As such, you can do something like this, following a similar format to pythonic833 because it was good (but with timestamps in the middle per the [Keras LSTM](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM) documentation asking for `[batch, timesteps, feature]`):

### Input generation

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

num_timesteps = 100
num_features = 5
num_observations = 2

input_list = [[[np.random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(num_features)]
   for _ in range(num_timesteps)]
    for _ in range(num_observations)]

input_arr = np.array(input_list)  # shape (2, 100, 5)
```

### Model construction

Then you can process the inputs:

```py
input1 = layers.Input(shape=(num_timesteps, 2,))
input2 = layers.Input(shape=(num_timesteps, 3))
x2 = layers.Dense(8, activation='relu')(input2)
x = layers.concatenate([input1,x2], axis=2) # This produces tensors of shape (None, 100, 10)
x = layers.LSTM(units=24)(x)
x = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(inputs=[input1, input2] , outputs=[x])
model.compile(
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['acc']
)
```

### Results

```py
inp1_np = input_arr[:, :, :2]
inp2_np = input_arr[:, :, 2:]
model.predict([inp1_np, inp2_np])
```

which produces

```py
array([[0.44117224],
       [0.23611131]], dtype=float32)
```

Other explanations about basis expansion to check out:

1. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/527258/embedding-data-into-a-larger-dimension-space
2. https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/2ffejw/why_dont_researchers_use_the_kernel_method_in/

Comment: Please notice I want embedding and not Dense here: x2 = layers.Dense(8, activation='relu')(input2)

Comment: I don't think it works that way. Keras Embedding layers map positive numbers into dense vectors, i.e. take in a 2D input of shape `(batch_size, input_length)` and returns a 3D output of `(batch_size, input_length, output_dim)`. This means it maps each element of `[0, 1, 0]` into a vector, e.g. `[[a,b], [c,d], [a,b]]`. Passing the one-hot encoding into a dense vector should still be able to learn about associations between the activated indices by the similarity of weights.

Comment: So what can be done here? Dense doesnt work (because it will learn a different set of weight per timestamp), is there a way to incorporate the other expansions to the NN?

Comment: I think it works out. From the Keras documentation for Dense, "Note: If the input to the layer has a rank greater than 2, then Dense computes the dot product between the inputs and the kernel along the last axis of the inputs and axis 0 of the kernel (using tf.tensordot). For example, if input has dimensions (batch_size, d0, d1), then we create a kernel with shape (d1, units), and the kernel operates along axis 2 of the input, on every sub-tensor of shape (1, 1, d1) (there are batch_size * d0 such sub-tensors). The output in this case will have shape (batch_size, d0, units)."

Comment: This means that the same weights are applied to each of the (batch_size, timestamp)  entries the same way.

Comment: Can u please explain how u understand that this the same weights? not sure I got it

Comment: Let's translate the example to our case, we have tensors of shape (batch_size, timesteps, 3) and a kernel is created with shape (3, 8). Explicitly, this means it'll create 8 linear functions + an activation that take in 3 inputs each (with different weights). Then it says these 8 functions are applied to each of the sub-tensors, of which there are (batch_size * timesteps many). For us, this means that each subtensor (1 x 1 x 3) gets put into those same 8 functions, which produces a result of shape (1 x 1 x 8). Then putting it all together, we get an output of shape (batch_size, timesteps, 8).